# why does python string formatting need a tuple? Why doesn't a list work?

Tags: python

I was surprised that python's percent-style formatting won't accept a list and seems to only accept tuples. What is special about tuples here? Why does the list throw the error?

```
In [1]: '%s %s' % ('hello', 'kilojoules')                                                     
Out[1]: 'hello kilojoules'

In [2]: '%s %s' % ['hello', 'kilojoules']                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-764f27542c69> in <module>
----> 1 '%s %s' % ['hello', 'kilojoules']

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: Trivial answer: because that's how it's [specified](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). Why this decision was made is off-topic for Stack Overflow; maybe try [comp.lang.python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CompLangPython)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using to format strings is a special syntax. In the list example you show, it is converting the non-tuple (a list) into a string before attempting to use it for formatting purposes.

You can do what you're trying to do by using the `format` method.

```
In [1]: "{} {}".format(*['hello', 'kilojoules'])
```

Doing it this way is recommended anyway, [as it is preferred](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: It may not be deprecated, but it is specifically discouraged in the docs. Unless you are maintaining an old code base, you should stick to either `str.format` or f-string literals

Answer (score 2):

Also, with the latest updates in python3.6, you can use f-Strings like this:

```
> great = "hello"
> name = "kilojoules"

> f"{great} {name}"
'hello kilojoules'
```

This [website](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) gives a good summary of the different ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html) answers your question directly: "If format specifier requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple object. Otherwise, values must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the format string, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary)." A list is neither, so it won't do.

Like others have pointed out, you could just use `.format` for a more modern approach, or even the still more modern f-string, which is as concise as your original example:

```
one_way = '{} {}'.format(*['hello', 'kilojoules'])
lst = ['hello', 'kilojoules']
another_way = f'{lst[0]} {lst[1]}'
```

Comment: Your example of the 'more modern f string' is missing the f bit :P

Comment: Thanks @shadow - nasty oversight :); I blame the painful way of moving code between my IDE and SO (although I'm really the only one to blame); fixed it.